# Failed to process resources, see aapt output below for details

Tags: android, apk, aapt

I'm trying to generate my apk for my app and I ran this command:

```
 ./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace --debug
```

and I got the error above.. after stackTrace I got this one:

```
12:19:05.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
12:19:05.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
12:19:05.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
12:19:05.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
12:19:05.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
12:19:05.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
12:19:05.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
12:19:05.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
12:19:05.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
12:19:05.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
12:19:05.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
12:19:05.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
12:19:05.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:512)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:249)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
12:19:05.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 31 more
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:809)
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:797)
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:491)
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 45 more
12:19:05.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process /Users/talshani/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/28.0.2/aapt with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/talshani/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-28/android.jar -M /Users/talshani/app/mobile_app/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/talshani/app/mobile_app/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release -m -J /Users/talshani/app/mobile_app/android/app/build/generated/source/r/release -F /Users/talshani/app/mobile_app/android/app/build/intermediates/res/release/resources-release.ap_ -D /Users/talshani/app/mobile_app/android/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/release/manifest_keep.txt --custom-package com.vitalacy.dashboard -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/talshani/app/mobile_app/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/release --no-version-vectors}
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:34)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:807)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 47 more
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process /Users/talshani/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/28.0.2/aapt with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/talshani/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-28/android.jar -M /Users/talshani/app/mobile_app/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/talshani/app/mobile_app/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release -m -J /Users/talshani/app/mobile_app/android/app/build/generated/source/r/release -F /Users/talshani/app/mobile_app/android/app/build/intermediates/res/release/resources-release.ap_ -D /Users/talshani/app/mobile_app/android/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/release/manifest_keep.txt --custom-package com.vitalacy.dashboard -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/talshani/app/mobile_app/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/release --no-version-vectors}
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:48)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1237)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:911)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:822)
12:19:05.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:664)
12:19:05.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:48)
12:19:05.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:58)
12:19:05.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/talshani/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/28.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
12:19:05.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:395)
12:19:05.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
12:19:05.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 9 more
```

this is my app/build.gradle file:

```
  apply plugin: "com.android.application"

 buildscript {
 repositories {
 maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
 dependencies {
 // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
 // quickly to Android tooling updates
 classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
   }
  }
   apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
     repositories {
   maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
  import com.android.build.OutputFile


    project.ext.react = [
     entryFile: "index.js"
      ]

    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
    def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

   android {
   compileSdkVersion 28
   buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
     }
    defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.vitalacy.dashboard"
     minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
       }
    }
    signingConfigs {
       release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
                }
               }
              }
      splits {
          abi {
         reset()
         enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
         }
        }
     buildTypes {
        release {
          minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
   }
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
 dependencies {
  compile project(':react-native-fabric')
  compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
  compile project(':react-native-spinkit')
  compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
  compile project(':react-native-picker')
  compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
  compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
  compile project(':react-native-firebase')
  compile project(':react-native-fcm')
  compile project(':react-native-device-info')
  compile project(':react-native-config')
  implementation project(':react-native-picker')
  implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
  implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
  implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
  implementation project(':react-native-svg')
  implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
  implementation project(':react-native-spinkit')
  implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
  implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
  implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
  implementation project(':react-native-config')
  implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"
  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02"
  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0' //17.3.1
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
     transitive = true;
    }

   }

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

and this is my android/build.gradle:

```
      buildscript {
     repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
     }
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        }
       }


     allprojects {
      repositories {
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
          mavenLocal()
          google()
          jcenter()

        maven {
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                 }

           }
        }

  ext {
   compileSdkVersion = 28
   targetSdkVersion = 28
   buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
   supportLibVersion = "28.0.0-rc02"
   googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
   oreoEXPERIMENTAL = "yes"
         }

  subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
      if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 28
            buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
           }
         }
      }
   }
```

I have been trying many hours to solve this issue but nothing help for now,
when im doing my debug app there is no problem.

-in the res folder I have those folders: drawable-hdpi-v4,drawable-mdpi-v4,drawable-xhdpi-v4,drawable-xxhdpi-v4,drawable-xxxhdpi-v4,mipmap-hdpi,mipmap-mdpi,mipmap-xhdpi,mipmap-xxhdpi,mipmap-xxxhdpi,values... I don't think im using drawable but I know im using mipmap.

Thank you so much for the help!

**Solution:**

not sure that this is the right solution but it help me to keep going, it was to delete all the folders with the drawable. btw the --debug just confused me and didn't help me to see the error clear (--stacktrace is enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change **com.android.tools.build:gradle** version inside android/build.gradle file.

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'

and also check your res folder there should not be any corrupted file.

Comment: do you mean to change my build gradle to the one you told me? why does it will make different?

Comment: Yes. You have to change with the mentioned version. This version has that fix.

Comment: and in the res folder I have those folders:
drawable-hdpi-v4,drawable-mdpi-v4,drawable-xhdpi-v4,drawable-xxhdpi-v4,drawable-xxxhdpi-v4,mipmap-hdpi,mipmap-mdpi,mipmap-xhdpi,mipmap-xxhdpi,mipmap-xxxhdpi,values... I don't think im using drawable but I know im using mipmap.
what should I do?

Comment: First check by doing change the version. If everything works fine then no need to check res folder.

Comment: same issue after changing the version

Comment: do you have any other suggestion please?

Comment: what version of android studio are you using?

Comment: im not using android studio but I already solved it you can see in the first post. I have a different problem you can see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514541/getting-the-old-code-when-creating-apk-for-new-version?noredirect=1#comment91968968_52514541