# Getting the old code when creating apk for new version

Tags: android, apk

im trying to test my app before uploading to the store and when I create the apk by

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

I see in the logs the new dependencies that I added but when im trying to test it:

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

I see the old code...
when im testing with the debug mode there is no problem and I see my new code

**What I have been trying so far:**

1. ./gradlew clean
2. delete my build folder and build again+restart my computer
3. delete my android folder and build again

   **I deleted the app from my phone after every try**

   **I'm using the old keystore from the previous version**

   **I'm not using visual studio im using vsc (my code is react native)**

   this is my app/build.gradle file:

   ```
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"

   buildscript {
   repositories {
   maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      }
    dependencies {
   classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
     }
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
     repositories {
     maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      }
     import com.android.build.OutputFile


      project.ext.react = [
      entryFile: "index.js"
       ]

      apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
      def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
      def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

      android {
      compileSdkVersion 28
      buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
      dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
     }
     defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.vitalacy.dashboard"
     minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
   multiDexEnabled true
   ndk {
       abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
      }
   }
   signingConfigs {
      release {
       if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
           storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
           storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
           keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
           keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
               }
              }
             }
     splits {
         abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
       universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
       include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
       }
    buildTypes {
       release {
         minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
     }
   // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
   applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
       // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
       // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
       def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
       def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
       if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
           output.versionCodeOverride =
                   versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
      }
     }
    }

    dependencies {
     compile project(':react-native-fabric')
     compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
     compile project(':react-native-spinkit')
      compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
     compile project(':react-native-picker')
     compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
     compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
     compile project(':react-native-firebase')
     compile project(':react-native-fcm')
     compile project(':react-native-device-info')
     compile project(':react-native-config')
     implementation project(':react-native-picker')
     implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
     implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
     implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
     implementation project(':react-native-svg')
     implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
     implementation project(':react-native-spinkit')
     implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
     implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
     implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
     implementation project(':react-native-config')
     implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
     implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"
     implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02"
     implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0' //17.3.1
     implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
      compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
       transitive = true;
         }

       }

   task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into 'libs'
     }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
   ```

and this is my android/build.gradle:

```
      buildscript {
     repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
     }
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        }
       }


     allprojects {
      repositories {
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
          mavenLocal()
          google()
          jcenter()

        maven {
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                 }

           }
        }

  ext {
   compileSdkVersion = 28
   targetSdkVersion = 28
   buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
   supportLibVersion = "28.0.0-rc02"
   googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
   oreoEXPERIMENTAL = "yes"
         }

  subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
      if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 28
            buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
           }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: did you try to delete *workspace* file and open again android studio and try ?

Comment: @VishalG.Gohel I'm not using visual studio, im using vsc bc my code is react native and all the commands im doing through terminal

Answer (score 0):

Build your apk with

```
./gradlew assemble
```

instead of

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```